# discord.py выдает ошибку при убирании роли

Tags: python, discord.py

я написал код на обнаружении слов в сообщении автора:

````
async def on_message(message):

    if 'word'   in message.content.lower():
        author = message.author
        muterole = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles,id=772045965968408606)    
        await author.add_roles(muterole)
        await message.channel.send("не матерись, сенпай,тебе мут на 10 минут")
        await asyncio.sleep(1*60 )
        await autor.remove_roles(muterole)
        await client.process_commands(message)```

выдает ошибку: 

    ```await autor.remove_roles(muterole)
NameError: name 'autor' is not defined ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неверно написано `autor`

```
await author.remove_roles(muterole)
```